# How to set custom python path in Dockerfile

Tags: python, dockerfile

My base image having python 2.7.18  but i need (cannot change base image) to use python 3.8.2.
I wrote dockerfile as below. When run python version it is displaying python 2.7.18.

FROM custom_base image

USER root

RUN yum install -y  python-3.8.2

ENV PATH "/home/python/python-3.8.2/bin:$PATH"

ENV PYTHON_HOME /home/python/python-3.8.2

ENV PYTHONPATH /home/python/python-3.8.2/lib/python3.8

My question is how to set python version to 3.8.2 always. Do i need to set both PATH and export PYTHON_HOME.

Comment: As @Arleme pointed out, you are probably doing something like `python --version`, which will give you the python 2 version. And if you do `python3 --verions`, you should see the correct one being returned.

Comment: Maybe do a yum uninstall python2 and delete the old install dir before installing python3. But this is a pretty bad way to go about it. And to explicitly use Python3 when 2 is also installed, use either `python3` or `python38` or `python3.8` - whichever is the correct 3.8 binary.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `python3` command .

Comment: when i use python3 --version i get command not found

Comment: have you already try the other like `python3.8` `python38` or even `py`

Comment: if those commands above doesn't work try to find the binairies of your python in `/usr/bin/`